# WINAPI C++ GetDlgItem does not return a valid handle

Tags: c++, winapi, 64-bit

I am trying to get the handle of a child Window by its ID but to do it I have to double cast the ID, otherwise it won't work. Is there other way? What am I missing?

WINAPI x64 C++

Code:

```
#define BASE_ID 100
UINT8 i = 1;
CreateWindow(... (HMENU)BASE_ID + i, ...)

//later in code

HWND hWnd = GetDlgItem(hParent, BASE_ID + i); // This won't work (Returns null handle)
HWND hWnd = GetDlgItem(hParent, (int)((HMENU)BASE_ID + i)); //Works but I get compiler warning
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean with "This won't work"?  Does it not compile?  Runtime error?  [Edit] your question to include these important details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first way works just fine under normal conditions, and is what you should be using:

```
GetDlgItem(hParent, BASE_ID + i)
```

The reason it fails in your code is because `BASE_ID + i` (aka 101) is NOT the same ID that you pass to `CreateWindow()`.

When calling `CreateWindow()`, you are casting the `BASE_ID` constant BY ITSELF first, THEN adding `i` to that pointer, thus invoking pointer arithmetic, which ends up producing a different ID (104 on 32bit, 108 on 64bit) than what you are expecting (101).

As such, `GetDlgItem(hParent, BASE_ID + i)` fails to find a matching ID, whereas `GetDlgItem(hParent, (int)((HMENU)BASE_ID + i))` succeeds since it uses the same casting logic that you used when calling `CreateWindow()`, thus finding a matching ID.

[Casting has a higher precedence than addition](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), so `(HMENU)BASE_ID + i` is interpreted by the compiler as `((HMENU)BASE_ID) + i`.  You need to fix your parenthesis so that you perform the addition FIRST, THEN cast the result:

```
CreateWindow(... (HMENU)(BASE_ID + i), ...)
```

Then `GetDlgItem(hParent, BASE_ID + i)` will work as expected.